# Parallel inner loop slows down program

Tags: c, performance, openmp

I'm trying to optimize a program as an experiment.

When I parallelized the first two outer loops(with "it" and "i") I saw significant difference on execution time. But when I tried to parallelize the inner most loop the program became much slower than sequential one. I also tried using reduction but the result was the same.

Is this something that I should expect or I made a mistake on the parallelization?

When I use the "nowait" clause it runs faster than the other two previous parallelizations.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(it,i,j) firstprivate(u,sigma,dt,mu)
{
for (it = 0; it < itime; it++) {

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum = 0.0;


    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j+=1) {

      sum += sigma[i * n + j] * (u[j] - u[i]);
    }

    #pragma omp atomic write
   uplus[i]= (u[i] + dt * (mu - u[i])) + dt * sum / divide;

    if (u[i] > uth) {
      #pragma omp atomic write
      uplus[i] = 0.0;

      if (it >= ttransient) {
        #pragma omp atomic
        omega1[i] += 1.0;
      }
   }
}

}//omp end
```

Comment: The inner loop is doing very little work. Splitting up the tasks might take more time than actually doing the calculations.

Comment: @BoPersson I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: You are accessing a single variable (`sum`) from inside. Synchronising that may take quite some time and spoil the benefit.